# Python doit dynamic actions

Tags: python, doit

I am using [Python doit](https://pydoit.org/contents.html) and would like to dynamically generate actions. The following code creates a list of commands that I would like doit to execute:

```
dirs = ['a','b','c']

def task_build():

    def create_cmd_string(directories=dirs):
        cmds = []
        for dir in directories:
            cmds.append(f"rsync -a {dir} ../package")
        return cmds

    return {
        'actions': [
            "mkdir -p ../package",
            create_cmd_string,
        ],
        'verbosity': 2,
    }
```

The only issue is that doit only runs the first element in the list:

```
"rsync -a a ../package"
```

And I would like it to do the following:

```
"rsync -a a ../package"
"rsync -a b ../package"
"rsync -a c ../package"
```

I have tried using [CmdAction](https://pydoit.org/tasks.html#cmd-action) and passing in different data types but neither of these methods worked. I'm thinking the next solution would be to create [dynamic subtasks](https://pydoit.org/tasks.html#sub-task-selection) but feel like I am missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your problem is that you are adding a list *inside* another list.
Try:

```
'actions': ["mkdir -p ../package"] + create_cmd_string,
```